# remove item from cart rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cart

I'm building E store in rails. I´m trying to remove Items from the cart but I´m not sure how I would do that. I´m not sure were to start since I'm  a total noob and been following a tutorial which doesn't include how to add delete function to the items.

here is a link to github repo `github.com/DadiHall/brainstore`

can anyone advise me here?

what I have so far is

routes.rb

```
  resource :cart, only: [:show] do
    post "add", path: "add/:id", on: :member
     delete "remove", path: "destroy/:id", on: :member

    get :checkout
  end
```

in carts_controller.rb

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :initialize_cart

    def add
        @cart.add_item params[:id]
        session["cart"] = @cart.serialize
        product = Product.find params[:id]
        redirect_to :back, notice: "Added #{product.name} to cart."
    end

    def show

    end

    def checkout
        @order_form = OrderForm.new user: User.new
        @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
    end

    #Delete
    def destroy
     redirect_to cart_path 
   end


end
```

in the views/cart/show.html.erb

```
 <% @cart.items.each do |item| %>

    <tr>
    <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag item.product.image.thumb %><%= link_to item.product.name, item.product %></td>
    <td><%= item.total_price %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Empty Cart', cart_path(@cart), method: :delete, confirm: 'are you sure?' %>
</td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

cart.rb model

```
class Cart
    attr_reader :items

    def self.build_from_hash hash
        items = if hash ["cart"] then 
            hash["cart"] ["items"].map do |item_data|
        CartItem.new item_data["product_id"], item_data["quantity"]
        end

    else
        []
    end

        new items
    end


  def initialize items = []
    @items = items
  end

  def add_item product_id
    item = @items.find { |item| item.product_id == product_id }
    if item
      item.increment
    else
      @items << CartItem.new(product_id)
    end
  end

  def empty?
    @items.empty?
  end

  def count
    @items.length
  end

  def serialize 
    items = @items.map do |item| 
        {
            "product_id" => item.product_id, 
            "quantity" => item.quantity
        }
    end

    {

            "items" => items
    }


  end

  def total_price
    @items.inject(0) { |sum, item| sum + item.total_price }
  end




end
```

cart_item.rb model

```
class CartItem
attr_reader :product_id, :quantity

  def initialize product_id, quantity = 1
    @product_id = product_id
    @quantity = quantity
  end

  def increment
    @quantity = @quantity + 1
  end

  def product
    Product.find product_id
  end

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end


end
```

Comment: Can you share the tutorial or the your code?

Comment: Hi here is the link to the tutorial, I signed up for free trial https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/build-a-store-with-a-payment-gateway-in-rails

Comment: I don't have access to this course, give you share your code on github so that I can take a look.

Comment: absolutely, here is the link to the github repo https://github.com/DadiHall/brainstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your destroy path in your carts controller you have not destroyed the object yet.

so what you have to do there is

routes.rb

```
delete 'remove', path: 'destroy/:id'
```

carts_controller.rb

```
def remove
  cart = session['cart']
  item = cart['items'].find { |item| item['product_id'] == params[:id] }
  if item
    cart['items'].delete item
  end
  redirect_to cart_path
end
```

views/carts/show.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to 'remove', remove_cart_path(item.product_id), method: :delete %></td>
```